# Flexbox, compressing other inline elements to show 100% hovered element

Tags: css, flexbox

Below, I have 4 elements lined up using `flexbox`. I got it to work so that when I hover over one of the elements, it makes that element `100%` and compresses the other elements.

The problem that I'm running into is that the transition is not working properly.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-left: 2px solid #777;
  border-right: 2px solid #777;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: orange;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container div:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know of a way to make the transition work with this flexbox example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I just needed to set a defining width.

The issue was it was trying to transition to `100%` width without knowing what to transition **from**.

Setting the width to `0px` or `0%` fixes the transition animation.

**Note*** This solution is the one to use if you're looking for IE 10 & 11 support. The above `flex-basis` solution will not work on IE.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-left: 2px solid #777;
  border-right: 2px solid #777;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: orange;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container div:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Animate the `flex-basis`

*This won't work on IE though, for that one need to use `width`*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  overflow: hidden;            /* added so any content hides */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-left: 2px solid #777;
  border-right: 2px solid #777;
  transition: flex-basis .5s;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: orange;
}
.container div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container div:hover {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Note** this solution does not work for IE 11 since it uses `flex-basis`.

Comment: @HunterTurner Sigh!...updated my answer with a note. And I don't mind if you want to accept your own answer instead because of this.

Comment: okay. Your solution is the best though because it uses flexbox. It's just a shame that IE exists, haha. Once IE is obliterated I'll go back and accept your answer xD